# Need to run GPSBabel command on txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, gpx, gpsbabel

I'm using windows 10. My current project requires me to merge several TXT files into a single one. Problem is that the TXT files has all the same name and what differentiate them is their folder name.

For example:

Folder1

- Folder with a 13 digits random name

  - gpsdata.txt
- Folder with a 13 digits random name

  - gpsdata.txt
    - Folder with a 13 digits random name
  - gpsdata.txt

I tried using the following BATCH command but it overwrites the file and I end with only the track from the last gpsdata.txt file.

```
FOR /R C:\FOLDER1 %%i IN (metadata.txt) DO X:\GPSBabel\gpsbabel -t 
-i xcsv,style=C:\mystyle.style -f %%i -o gpx -F C:\FOLDER2\gpsdata.gpx
```

Is there a way to 'copy and merge' these txt files and transform then into gpx via .BAT using GPSBabel?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The FOR loop does not seem to be producing what you want. Try constructing the FOR loop alone until %%i comes out as you expect.

```
FOR /R C:\FOLDER1 %%i IN (metadata.txt) DO (ECHO %%~i)
```

You might want the FOR loop to produce a path to every `metadata.txt` file. Does this produce what you are seeking?

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B C:\FOLDER1\metadata.txt') DO (echo %%i)
```

That might make the code look like:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B "C:\FOLDER1\metadata.txt"') DO (
    X:\GPSBabel\gpsbabel -t -i xcsv,style=C:\mystyle.style -f "%%~i" -o gpx -F C:\FOLDER2\gpsdata.gpx
)
```

Comment: Oh didn't know how to echo a parameter...it seems like if you put it inside parenthesis it work?...I'll try...thanks

Comment: thanks for your comment...It almost does what I need, except that every time it run the code, it rewrites the gpsdata.gpx file..... but I'll try with your suggestion and see how I can tweak it to work...

Comment: @SuporteJM, I have no knowledge of the `gpsbabel` executable. Does it concatenate the file to `C:\FOLDER2\gpsdata.gpx`?

Comment: Hi @lit, no it actually converts txt file into GPX files....but I was able to achieve my goal with your support of 'echoing' the parameter...

Comment: @SuporteJM, I am glad to hear you have reached your goal. Please choose one of the three (3) answers as the "best" answer by using the check mark icon. I am not asking you to select mine unless you consider it the "best" answer. This is how SO lets others know what worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `for /R`, neither do use `for /F` with `dir /S`, since you have got a flat directory structure. What you need is `for /D`, or `for /F` together with `dir` in order to control sorting.

1. Approach using `for /D` (sub-directories are iterated in the order as returned by the file system):

   ```cmd
    rem // Prepare an empty file to begin with:
    copy nul "C:\FOLDER1\metadata.txt" > nul
    rem // Iterate over the immediate sub-directories:
    for /D %%I in ("C:\FOLDER1\?????????????") do (
        rem // Check whether the current sub-directory contains the text file:
        if exist "%%~I\gpsdata.txt" (
            rem // Append the text file to the result file:
            copy /B "C:\FOLDER1\metadata.txt" + "%%~I\gpsdata.txt" "C:\FOLDER1\metadata.txt" > nul
        )
    )
   ```
2. Approach using `for /F` and `dir` (sub-directories are sorted in alphabetic manner due to `/O:N`):

   ```cmd
    rem // Change into target directory:
    pushd "C:\FOLDER1" && (
        rem // Prepare an empty file to begin with:
        copy nul "metadata.txt" > nul
        rem // Iterate over the immediate sub-directories:
        for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /A:D-L-H-S /O:N "?????????????"') do (
            rem // Check whether the current sub-directory contains the text file:
            if exist "%%I\gpsdata.txt" (
                rem // Append the text file to the result file:
                copy /B "metadata.txt" + "%%I\gpsdata.txt" "metadata.txt" > nul
            )
        )
        rem // Return from target directory:
        popd
    )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For those that may need to convert using GPSBabel on several txt files with the same name inside different subfolders to get a GPX out of them, I was able to perform this with the following batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B C:\FOLDER1\metadata.txt') DO "X:\GPSBabel\gpsbabel.exe" -t -i xcsv,style=C:\mystyle.style -f "%%i" -x discard,hdop=10,vdop=20 -x duplicate,location -x simplify,crosstrack,error=0.001k -o gpx -F "%%i".gpx
set f=
for /F "delims=" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B C:\FOLDER1\*.gpx') DO set f=!f! -f "%%f"
"X:\GPSBabel\gpsbabel.exe" -t -i gpx %f% -x discard,hdop=10,vdop=20 -x duplicate,location -x simplify,crosstrack,error=0.001k -x nuketypes,waypoints -o gpx -F C:\FOLDER2\%DATE:~6,4%_%DATE:~3,2%_%DATE:~0,2%_LOG.gpx
```

The first part just create a GPX file for every TXT file inside their same folder.
The second part is taking all those GPX file and merging them into a single one on a different folder setting the name of the file as "current_date"_log.gpx